# Is there anyway that I can calculate the number of elements in this array?

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    srand (time( NULL));
     const char* words[] = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wedensday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};


    int Randnum = rand() % 6;
    cout << words[Randnum] << endl;


}
```

So basically what I want to do is that instead of having that `int Randnum = rand() % 6 ;`, I want to have  a variable that changes with the array. something like `int Randnum rand() % totalwords;`. I tried using `sizeof(words` but that would only work if I know how many bytes each word took. Is there any way you guys can think of that would let me count each word as 1 item so when the array grows the random number range does too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this:

```
sizeof(words)/sizeof(words[0])
```

which will give you 7.

And `int Randnum = rand() % 7` give you a random number between 0 and 6 and `words[Randnum]` is a random day in the week.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sizeof(words)/sizeof(char *)
```

As the entries in `words` are `char *` and the total size of `words` will be the number of bytes to store the 7 character pointers